# Function Cost Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

Neural networks use cost functions to minimize error and make the model better for supervised models.
Example:

> Regression cost Function:
> Regression models deal with predicting a continuous value for example salary of an employee, price of a car, loan prediction, etc. A cost function used in the regression problem is called “Regression Cost Function”. They are calculated on the distance-based error as follows:
> Error = y-y’
> Where,
> Y – Actual Input
> Y’ – Predicted output
> [enter link description here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/02/cost-function-is-no-rocket-science/)

In unsupervised I don't have training. How works the function cost in clustering? Do they use competitive algorithms and select the output that has the best result?

Comment: Every neural network has some loss function that is being optimized, but the particular form of that loss function will depend on the specifics of the network. What specific unsupervised neural network model do you have in mind? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I see you've added a completely generic definition of a regression loss; [tag:Autoencoders] are an example of NNs that are unsupervised and can use a regression loss. Not all neural networks use the regression loss, so an alternative family of unsupervised NNs could use a different loss.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to learn an algorithm (any algorithm capable of learning) needs to be able to somehow track its progress so that it knows if it improves or not. For this, the algorithm needs a cost function. Regardless if it is a supervised or unsupervised learning problem, you always need some kind of function that tells you if you are going "in the right direction". Sometimes the cost function may be implicit (e.g. when calculating an arithmetic average, you are finding a value that minimizes squared error), but it is always there. Even if you generated a bunch of random solutions and just picked "the best one", you would need a cost function that tells you which one is the best.

Since this is a very basic question, I'd recommend you to start with some introductory machine learning course or handbook that explains this in greater detail.